# UIPickerView as a Subview

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, subview

I am trying to create a Dialog Box in which contains a UIPickerView. I can get it to work without the Subview tied around it but I always end up with an Uncaught error. Any help?

Comment: You need to set your answer as accepted otherwise it will always appear as unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently I fixed by messing with this method -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component